# I want to disable aui submit button

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the submit button for the user.

User can submit only one time , if next time login in the page, submit button should disable, how to do that. Please help me.

```
<td colspan="7"><aui:button name="submitAction" id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Submit"  /></td>
```

Comment: What have you done so far , share whatever code that u have done till now ?

Comment: i tried below code for disable button.<aui:form name="frmaddInvetoryDetails" id="frmaddInvetoryDetails" action="<%=processActionURL.toString()%>"  method="post" onsubmit="JavaScript:document.getElementById('submitbtn').disabled=true">

Comment: remove javascript: from that

Comment: i removed but it is not disable the button, its because of I am using AUI?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is `aui` but in HTML5, I believe this can be done using `localStorage` if you prefer to use client side database.

Here's a sample code in HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">


    function setFlag(){     
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
        localStorage.flag="1";  
        btn.disabled="true";
    }

    function check(){

    alert("flag="+localStorage.flag);

    var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");

        if(localStorage.flag=="1"){
            btn.disabled="true";
        }else{      
            btn.onclick= setFlag;   

        }

    }

</script>

<body onload="check()">

<input type="Button" id="btn1" value="Button1">

</body>
</html>
```